# Showfreqs and showwaves over background image?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm wanting to get FFMPEG to export my podcast audio to a file I can upload to youtube that is visually interesting.

currently I am using the following piece of code, which I don't fully grasp:

```
ffmpeg -i E04_ProphetsPrey.wav -filter_complex \
"    [0:a]showfreqs=mode=line:ascale=log:fscale=rlog:s=1280x518,pad=1280:720[vs]; \
 [0:a]showfreqs=mode=line:ascale=log:fscale=rlog:s=1x1[ss]; \
 [0:a]showwaves=s=1280x202:mode=p2p[sw]; \
 [vs][ss]overlay=w[bg]; \
 [bg][sw]overlay=0:H-h,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='\"Rated80s Prophets Prey\" by Comics On Film'[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy -threads 0 output.mkv
```

what I would like to do is set a (branded) background image, and have showfreqs render over it on the top half and showwaves render over it on the bottom half.

Is that possible, and if so could you provide me a detailed example?

(I'm on arch linux)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showfreqs=mode=line:ascale=log:fscale=log:s=1280x518[sf]; \
 [0:a]showwaves=s=1280x202:mode=p2p[sw]; \
 [sf][sw]vstack[fg]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:-1,crop=iw:720[bg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='\"Rated80s Prophets Prey\" by Comics On Film'[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a libopus output.mkv
```

- [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) vertically stacks the two effects. It is easier and usually faster than using overlay to do so.
- The example background image was oversized, so [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) made the image 1280x720.
- The vstacked effects are then layered above the background using the overlay filter, format filter makes a more pixel format compatible with non-FFmpeg based players (you can remove it if just uploading to YouTube), and finally [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) makes the text.
- If you get `[overlay] Unable to parse option value "auto"` your version is too old and you should upgrade. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I also add -threads to this to speed it up?

Comment: @Jeremy No, because libx264 automatically chooses the optimal number of threads for your hardware, so overriding it by manually adding `-threads` may cause it to be slower. If you want it to be faster then use a faster `-preset`; if you see no improvement then the filtering is the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you. You are very informed and live up to the name Lord Neckbeard.