# FFMPEG use -strict -2

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I've been recently using the command below

```
Ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showfreqs=mode=line:ascale=log:fscale=log:s=1280x518[sf]; \
 [0:a]showwaves=s=1280x202:mode=p2p[sw]; \
 [sf][sw]vstack[fg]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:-1,crop=iw:720[bg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='\"Rated80s Prophets Prey\" by Comics On Film'[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a libopus output.mp4
```

from this post [Showfreqs and showwaves over background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029575/showfreqs-and-showwaves-over-background-image).

> However I changed the output file to from output.mkv to output.mp4 as I would prefer to use mp4

I get the below error

[mp4 @ 0x7f962b816800] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
[libopus @ 0x7f962b819800] 1 frames left in the queue on closing

The main information from that error is

> opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.

but where do I use -strict -2 within the command to make the command possible

Answer (score 3):

You can add it anywhere after the last input and before the output URL.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -strict -2 -filter_complex ...
```

or

```
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a libopus -strict -2 output.mp4
```

You can also write it as `-strict experimental`.