# FFmpeg Error: Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM and incorrect codec parameters

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

Using FFmpeg to record the live stream.

Actually, it is a platform where someone can stream live (camera or screen) and others can join the stream as views.

The person who is streaming live has the option to record that stream. For recording stream `FFmpeg` is being used.

The stream is being recorded in the `WEBM` file format.

The issue is FFmpeg is throwing the error.

> Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM. 
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

The command that records the stream is below.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -protocol_whitelist pipe udp rtp 
-fflags+genpts -f sdp -i pipe:0 -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy 
-map 0:a:0 -strict -2 -c:a copy -flags +global_header 1234_VIDEO_1671647432529.webm
```

| Service | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Server(EC2) | AWS Linux 2 |
| FFmpeg version | 4.3.2-static |

**NOTE**: 2 weeks back the same command was working.

Comment: hey have you found any solution to this?

have exactly the same problem, and as you mentioned, all was working before (2 weeks) - seems an ffmpeg update broke something?

thanks

Comment: @mostamazingname We have not updated the FFmpeg, it was working, and thereafter it stopped working with `h.264`. We changed it to VP8 and it worked. Still not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: yeah i changed to vp8 and forced opus codec and it seems to have fixed it without even updating ffmpeg. maybe some other dependancy of ffmpeg? no idea!

Comment: @mostamazingname Yeah, no idea why it has stopped working suddenly, could not find any internal FFmpeg files to auto-update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your video and audio flags are both set to `copy`:

  - `-c:v copy -c:a copy`
- ...which means `ffmpeg` will take the video and audio data directly from the (presumably piped-in RTP) and will try to save them directly into the output WebM file.

  - ...so this only works when the input data's codec is actually supported by the output file-format.
- ...in this case, your RTP stream contained a video or audio (or both) track/stream that is not compatible with WebM.

  - WebM itself is a container format (derived from Matroska) that only supports a small number of audio and video codecs (by design), whereas other container-formats like MPEG-4, Matroska, and AVI support a wider range of codecs.
- `ffmpeg` does not pre-validate your command-line on startup, instead ffmpeg will blindly follow your instructions so you won't get that *"Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM."* error message until your input stream starts to contain data that cannot be stored in a WebM file using `copy`.

  - [This is mentioned in the ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-handling):

    > ffmpeg does not validate if the specified encoder can convert the selected stream or if the converted stream is acceptable within the output format. This applies generally as well: when the user sets an encoder manually, the stream selection process cannot check if the encoded stream can be muxed into the output file. If it cannot, ffmpeg will abort and all output files will fail to be processed.
- The solution is to specify WebM-compatible codecs for both audio and video.

  - For video (`-c:v`), WebM only supports [VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) and [VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) - and *technically* [AV1](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AV1) as well:

    - For VP8, use `-c:v libvpx -crf 15 -b:v 1M`
    - For VP9, use `-c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0`
    - For AV1, use `-c:v libaom-av1 -crf 30 -b:v 0`
  - For audio, WebM only supports Opus and [Vorbis](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide):

    - For Opus, use `-c:a libopus`
    - For Vorbis, use `-c:a libvorbis`
- [Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to have ffmpeg *conditionally* choose](https://superuser.com/q/1180108/41739) to either `copy` or re-encode (using `-c:v libvpx`, etc) if the input stream is already using a codec that's compatible with the output file-format.

  - This isn't a problem with pre-recorded files as you can use `ffprobe` to detect the files' formats and *then* specify `ffmpeg`'s codecs based on that.
  - ...but if you're piping from a live-stream then it seems the least-worst-option is to just always-use VP9 ([VP8 and VP9](https://caniuse.com/webm) seem to share similar support levels, while [AV1's support is lacking](https://caniuse.com/av1) on Safari (iOS and macOS) and Edge.
- ...therefore, try this command-line (line-breaks added for readability):

  ```
  ffmpeg
      -loglevel debug
      -protocol_whitelist pipe udp rtp 
      -fflags+genpts
      -f sdp
      -i pipe:0
      -map 0:v:0
      -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0
      -map 0:a:0
      -strict -2
      -c:a libvorbis
      -flags +global_header
      -f webm
      1234_VIDEO_1671647432529.webm
  ```
- BTW I get the feeling the `-map 0:v:0` and `-map 0:a:0` options can be removed [as ffmpeg will pick the first audio stream and the first video stream by default](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map#Defaultbehavior), and [the `-strict -2` flag seems to be a cargo-cultish use to force Opus audio in MPEG-4 containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63521548/159145) - which you don't need if you're using WebM as your container format... so consider using this simpler version:

  ```
  ffmpeg
      -loglevel debug
      -protocol_whitelist pipe udp rtp 
      -fflags+genpts
      -f sdp
      -i pipe:0
      -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0
      -c:a libvorbis
      -flags +global_header
      -f webm
      1234_VIDEO_1671647432529.webm
  ```